# Looking up the cell with the closest time to my target time

Tags: excel, date, indexing, vlookup

Hi I have a set of data that has date time values down to the seconds. On another sheet I have another set of data with date time values broken down every minute. I'd like to be able to look up the closest minute time after the seconds bar. For example, if one cell has a time of 01:12:34 (1:12 and 34 seconds), i'd like for it to return 1:13:00. The catch is that in some cases, the next time after the 01:12:34 might not be until 1:15:00.

Ive tried using index match and setting the match type to 1 and that gives me the closest time before my target cell. So in the example above, it returns 1:12:00. The other match types dont seem to work (Too many NAs). I've tried an hlookup with matchtime set to 1 as well without any luck.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
    +-----------------------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|            Target Data            |    Minute Data    |        |  Expected Output  |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
| 12/29/17 15:10:14                 | 12/28/17 14:03:00 |        | 12/29/17 15:11:00 |
| 1/1/18 18:00:00                   | 12/28/17 14:04:00 |        | 1/1/18 18:01:00   |
| 1/2/18 2:52:04                    | 12/28/17 14:05:00 |        | 1/2/18 2:53:00    |
| 1/2/18 5:03:51                    | 12/28/17 14:06:00 |        | 1/2/18 5:04:00    |
| 1/2/18 7:00:00                    | 12/28/17 14:07:00 |        | 1/2/18 7:01:00    |
| 1/2/18 8:14:27                    | 12/28/17 14:08:00 |        | 1/2/18 8:15:00    |
| 1/2/18 8:45:30                    | 12/28/17 14:09:00 |        | 1/2/18 8:46:00    |
| 1/2/18 9:00:00                    | 12/28/17 14:10:00 |        | 1/2/18 9:01:00    |
| 1/2/18 9:11:37                    | 12/28/17 14:11:00 |        | 1/2/18 9:12:00    |
| 1/2/18 9:27:33                    | 12/28/17 14:12:00 |        | 1/2/18 9:28:00    |
| 1/2/18 9:40:15                    | 12/28/17 14:13:00 |        | 1/2/18 9:41:00    |
| 1/2/18 9:59:45                    | 12/28/17 14:14:00 |        | 1/2/18 10:00:00   |
| 1/2/18 10:10:00                   | 12/28/17 14:15:00 |        | 1/2/18 10:11:00   |
| 1/2/18 10:22:10                   | 12/28/17 14:16:00 |        | 1/2/18 10:28:18   |
| 1/2/18 10:30:58                   | 12/28/17 14:17:00 |        | 1/2/18 10:31:00   |
| 1/2/18 10:36:46                   | 12/28/17 14:18:00 |        | 1/2/18 10:37:00   |
| 1/2/18 10:44:03                   | 12/28/17 14:19:00 |        | 1/2/18 10:45:00   |
| 1/2/18 10:49:54                   | 12/28/17 14:20:00 |        | 1/2/18 10:50:00   |
| 1/2/18 10:57:26                   | 12/28/17 14:21:00 |        | 1/2/18 10:58:00   |
| 1/2/18 11:12:36                   | 12/28/17 14:22:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 11:27:05                   | 12/28/17 14:23:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 11:39:36                   | 12/28/17 14:24:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 12:01:55                   | 12/28/17 14:25:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 12:14:56                   | 12/28/17 14:26:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 12:32:44                   | 12/28/17 14:27:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 12:52:40                   | 12/28/17 14:28:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 13:25:08                   | 12/28/17 14:29:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 14:11:08                   | 12/28/17 14:30:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 14:16:32                   | 12/28/17 14:31:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 14:23:10                   | 12/28/17 14:32:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 14:26:38                   | 12/28/17 14:33:00 |        |                   |
| 1/2/18 14:28:33                   | 12/28/17 14:34:00 |        |                   |
| Col1                              | Col2              | NumCol |                   |
| Value 1                           | Value 2           | 123    |                   |
| This is a row with only one cell  |                   |        |                   |
| This row is testing html entities | Te<br />st        | 45     |                   |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way but...

[image]

```
target: full time stamp
minute: your minute table
expected over: {=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$5>A2,$B$2:$B$5))}
expected under: {=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$5<A2,$B$2:$B$5))}
dif1: C2-A2, dif2: A2-D2
final value: =IF(F2<E2,D2,C2)
```

You can probably combine some of those columns